# Select Tag Option Value not passing to url parameter on iOS

Tags: c#, html, ios, css, asp.net

I have a set of html select tags that serve to accomplish a a set of search parameters for a vehicle catalogue.
The html is as follows:

```
                                <div class="clearfix select-form padding-bottom-50">
                                    <div class="my-dropdown min-years-dropdown max-dropdown">
                                        <select name="year" class="css-dropdowns" tabindex="1" id="txtYear" runat="server" >
                                            <option value="">Search by Year</option>
                                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                            <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                            <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                            <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                            <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                            <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                            <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                            <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="my-dropdown min-years-dropdown max-dropdown">
                                        <select name="make" class="css-dropdowns" tabindex="1" id="txtMake" runat="server" >
                                            <option value="">Search by Make</option>
                                            <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
                                            <option value="FORD">FORD</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="my-dropdown min-years-dropdown max-dropdown">
                                        <select name="transmission" class="css-dropdowns" tabindex="1" id="txtTrans" runat="server" >
                                            <option value="">Search by Transmission</option>
                                            <option value="Automatic">Automatic</option>
                                            <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="my-dropdown min-years-dropdown max-dropdown">
                                        <select name="price" class="css-dropdowns" tabindex="1" id="txtPrice" runat="server" >
                                            <option value="">Search by Price</option>
                                            <option value="50000">&lt; R50,000</option>
                                            <option value="100000">&lt; R100,000</option>
                                            <option value="150000">&lt; R150,000</option>
                                            <option value="200000">&lt; R200,000</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="button" value="Search" class="pull-left btn-inventory margin-bottom-none md-button" runat="server" id="btnSearch" onserverclick="btnSearch_ServerClick1" />

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
```

On Codebehind:

```
protected void btnSearch_ServerClick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("usedsearch.aspx?make=" + txtMake.Value + "&year=" + txtYear.Value + "&trans=" + txtTrans.Value + "&price=" + txtPrice.Value);

    }
```

When browsing the site on an iphone, the values from the select tags are not passed to the URL Parameters(Parameter value is blank -> eg www.....com?Make=&Year=...).
However, on an android device, it works perfectly. Really confused.

Comment: Is the form valid HTML i.e. is that HTML at least wrapped in a FORM tag?

Comment: Using ASP.Net so one form tag on the master page. Rest of the application doesnt make use of form tags as per ASP.Net architecture.